# Is there a way to remotely test react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler, web-ide

I'm thinking to pass to a web app IDE like cloud9 to host my apps currently in development.
The problem with this is that i don't know how to test my code in the way I normally do with a simulator, locally.

I'm trying to develop on a remote server, and building on that remote server, an i want to test the app with my real device, with live reloading absolutely. If it's not possible to use my real device i could use an emulator and it's ok, but I'd prefer to use my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using metro-bundler, you can achieve this by using the **Tunnel** option in connection:

[image]

This will create a global link to communicate with any of your devices. Then you can easily use the **QR code** or just the generated **link** in your own mobile device using expo app.

Now you can debug and test with your actual physical phone or emulator without publish it.

Comment: I meant, without expo, i'm working on a non expo project